# question on the bounded sequence of extended real number system

Tags: analysis

I'm working through the extended real number system using the Analysis I texbook of Tao.

> **Definition 6.2.1** The extended real number system $R^∗$ is the real line $R$ with two additional elements attached, called $+∞$ and $−∞$. These elements are distinct from each other and also distinct from every real number. An extended real number $x$ is
> called finite iff it is a real number, and infinite iff it is equal to $+∞$ or
> $−∞$.

> **Definition 6.3.1** Let $(a_n)_{n=m}^∞$ be a sequence
> of real numbers. Then we define $sup(a_n)_{n=m}^∞$  to be the supremum of the
> set {$a_n : n ≥ m$}, and $inf(a_n)_{n=m}^∞$ to the infimum of the same set
> {$a_n : n ≥ m$}

> **Example**: Let $a_n := n$; thus  $(a_n)_{n=1}^∞$ is the sequence $1, 2, 3, 4, . . ..$
> Then the set {$a_n : n ≥ 1$} is just the positive integers {$1, 2, 3, 4, . . .$}.
> Then $sup(a_n)_{n=1}^∞$ = $+∞$ and $inf(a_n)_{n=1}^∞$ = $1$.
> $\quad$As this example shows, it is possible for the supremum or infimum
> of a sequence to be $+∞$ or $−∞$. However, if a sequence $(a_n)_{n=m}^∞$ is
> bounded, ***say bounded by $M$***, then all the elements $a_n$ of the sequence
> lie between $−M$ and $M$, so that the set {$a_n : n ≥ m$} has $M$ as an upper
> bound and $−M$ as a lower bound. Since this set is clearly non-empty,
> we can thus conclude that the supremum and infimum of a bounded
> sequence are real numbers (i.e., not $+∞$ and $−∞$).

My question is: what if $M$ is an element of $R^*$, then the sequence $(a_n)_{n=m}^∞$ can also be
bounded by $M$=$+∞$,then all the elements $a_n$ of the sequence
lie between $+∞$ and $−∞$, so the supremum and infimum of a bounded
sequence need not to be real numbers, i.e., they can be  $+∞$ or $−∞$. Am I right?  Thank you!

Comment: In the text, it is implicit that $M \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Is every sequence in $R^*$ bounded? As we have $+∞$ and $-∞$, I guess yes. @TheSilverDoe

Comment: Yes, all sequences in $R^*$ are bounded. They should have clarified that they are talking about bounded in $R$, in the paragraph.

Comment: Yes, all sequences in $R*$ are bounded ; that's why the term "bounded" refers here to sequences of $R*$ that are bounded in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you guys!